# WKWebView is crashing when trying to access photo library (iOS 12.2)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios12

In an app running iOS 12.2, I'm presenting a website using WKWebView.

Inside the webpage, when clicking on a button that tries to access the photos library the app crashes with the following trace:

[image]

How can I prevent this crash?

Comment: Have you edited your Info.plist to add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`?

Comment: @grooveplex yes. This crash is started appearing on iOS 12.2, it works on iOS 12, and previous versions. I'm thinking it might be an iOS 12.2 bug...